# First JavaScript test broken - I just can't figure this out

Tags: javascript, html

Ok so the HTML:

```
<body>

    <div class="title">
        <img src="img" alt=""/>
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><button onclick='homeClick()'>HOME</button></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="historybtn" onclick="workClick()">WORK</a></li>
            <li><a href="team.html" class="teambtn">TEAM</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html" class="contactbtn">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <p id="home1">Check</p>

    <p id="work1">Here's some text in the home div</p>

    <script src="mainapp.js"></script>
</body>
```

And I've got this script (mainapp.js as called above) that should change the p element/s... WHY WON'T IT WORK OMG rawr?!

```
    function homeClick() {
        document.getElementByID("home1").innerHTML = "Break a breaka one nine.";
    };

    function workClick() {
        document.getElementByID('work1').innerHTML = "Now it's the work text";
    };
```

Comment: Please, explain exactly what goes wrong (including any error messages) and consider rephrasing your question.

Answer (score 2):

Because, as the web console is telling you, there is no `getElementByID` function. There is, however, a `getElementById` function (note the lower case `d` at the end). JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Comment: Got to love that console. [How to open the JavaScript console in different browsers?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)

Comment: I knew this would only end in embarrassment. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Don't we all make these slip ups. Change `getElementByID` to `getElementById`
Cheers